# Meteor - Focus on text field not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, focus, textfield

I have a template that is rendered conditional on a session variable:

```
{{#if showTextField}}
  {{> textFieldTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

This is the template:

```
<template name="textFieldTemplate">
  <form class="item-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type new exercise...">
  </form>
</template>
```

And the JS that goes with it:

```
Template.textFieldTemplate.rendered = function () {
  this.$field = this.$('input');

  this.$field.focus();
});
```

This works great on my desktop browser; after setting showTextField to true, the field pops up and the cursor is blinking within the text field. On iphone safari, however, it doesn't work so well; text field shows up, but no cursor inside it and keyboard does not pop up. Any advice?

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems to be almost impossible to work around this issues. Definitely interested in a solution as well.